# ERM: Cardinality in ternary relationships

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

How can I read and/or specify cardinality (min/max) in ternary relationships of Entity-Relationship-Models (Chen-Notation)?

For example: A head visits several qualification with his associated employees. Now, I want to know how to specify the cardinalitys in Min-Max-Notation.

[image]

Here is another example with given cardinalitys and I want to know how to read it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Please give a reference to the ERM style you are using. There are many.

Comment: I've updated the question according to your suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ternary relationship can be read as follows:

For a given instance of E1 and a given instance of E2, there can only be one instance of E3 associated to both (via R).

For a given instance of E1 and E3, there can only be one instance of E2 associated to both (via R).

For a given instance of E2 and E3, there can be multiple instances of E1 associated to both (via R).

To specify the cardinalities in min-max notation, you have to ask: if I have an instance of "Head", how many instances of Employee and Qualification together can be associated to one "Head" (via HEQ). If your answer would be min 1 and max N you would write (1, N) or (1, *) above the line connecting "Head" and HEQ. Now you proceed to the next entity asking the equivalent question for this entity.