# ERD with OR condition

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I am trying to design an Entity Relationship Diagrham (ERD, EER ,ER) to describe a data architecture where a condition 1-1 is the result of two 0-1 relations that are have an OR logic between them.

In the [schema below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VB997.png) I am trying to indicate that every `Brand` has 1 and only 1 `Organization` OR `Brand Group`. In other words a `Brand` will always need to be linked to either an `Organization` or a `Brand Group`. What is the correct way to define that in an ERD?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is an official/standard way to indicate such a constraint (you're essentially looking for an "exclusive or" / XOR construct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not possible with classical ERD

- In [Chen's notation](https://vertabelo.com/blog/chen-erd-notation/) one could be tempted to use a ternary relation, with a total participation of `Brand` and a partial participation of the others.  But this would be wrong, since the ternary relation is about three entities participation (see explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924750/3723423)), and there is no way to express conditions between relations.
- In [Everest's notation](https://vertabelo.com/blog/crow-s-foot-notation/) (better known as "Crow's foot") the relationships are anyway at most binary, and nothing in the notation allows to add constraints.

### Solutions using Extended ERD

The EERD provide support for generalization (i.e. inheritance using an "is-a" relationship):

- Add a conceptual entity `Brand Owner` (or however you want to call it)
- Add an `IsA` relationship from `Organization` and `Brand group` to `Brand Owner`
- Replace the two relations between `Brand` and `Organization` and `Brand group`  with a one to many relation of `Brand` with `Brand Owner`

The `IsA` extension is noted with a triangle in the extended Chen notation. Unfortunately, there's no commonly agreed notation in Crow's foot notation (some use a circle with a bar on the side of the specialization, some use a kind of logical gate, and tool support is not guaranteed).

### Why not using UML?

With UML your tables would be classes,  you'd have to replace the crowfoots with multiplicity (it's straighforward, as it is on the same side).

The easiest ways would be to just add  an `{xor}` constraint between the two alternative `Brand` *associations* (the UML terminology for ER-relation).  If you prefer, you can also use a natural language constraint such as `{must be one of the two}`

But if you like the idea of generalization, UML provides it out of the box, and a notation for `«abstract»` classes even allows to  clarify that `Brand Owner` does not really exist and is just a virtual intermediary.